# SimpleXML Not Reading URL

Tags: php, url, simplexml

I'm trying to get the below code to work. Currently it just outputs nothing, a blank page.

```
if($vUrlDetails = simplexml_load_file($vUrl)) {
   // Do something
}
```

It works fine if I use `file_get_contents()` and save it to a file and then use `simplexml_load_file()`.

Are there restrictions on loading XML files over a URL using `simplexml_load_file()`?

Comment: Have you tried `$xml = simplexml_load_file($vUrl, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);`?

Comment: @user1190992, Already tried this, no luck there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try:

```php
<?php
  // http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('http://my.url.com/something.xml', 0, true);
?>
```